# Как правильно получить массив?

Tags: php

вот так получаю

```
foreach ($catAll as $allCat){
      $dropArray[]=['label' => $allCat->name, 'url' => ['/category/' . $allCat->slug_category]];
}
```

вот так вставляю в другой массив

```
 $menuArr[] = ['label' => $parent->name, 'url' => ['/category/' . $parent->slug_category],'items' => [$dropArray]];
var_dump($menuArr);
```

получаю так

```
Array ( 
    [label] => Для нее 
    [url] => Array ( 
        [0] => /category/Dlya-nee ) 
        [items] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [label] => Блузы/Рубашки 
                    [url] => Array ( [0] => /category/BluzyRubashki ) 
                ) 
                [1] => Array ( 
                    [label] => Большие размеры 
                    [url] => Array ( [0] => /category/Bolshie-razmery )
                ) 

            ) 
        ) 
    )
```

а надо 
вот так

```
Array ( 
[label] => Для нее 
[url] => Array ( 
    [0] => /category/Dlya-nee ) 
    [items] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [label] => Блузы/Рубашки 
                [url] => Array ( [0] => /category/BluzyRubashki ) 
            ) 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [label] => Большие размеры 
                [url] => Array ( [0] => /category/Bolshie-razmery )
            ) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: `'items' => $dropArray`, не?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените вставку вот так

```
$menuArr[] = [
  'label' => $parent->name,
  'url' => ['/category/' . $parent->slug_category],
  'items' => $dropArray
];
var_dump($menuArr);
```